# How do you get the weapon upstairs?

Tags: shadow-warrior-2

At the base above one of the shops it shows a weapon. I've tried climbing up everything, smashing things, but can't seem to get it.

Does it unlock later in the game or can you get it as soon as you are in the area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weapon is above Hideo's shop and is in an area that is blocked off. The gates to the stairs are locked off early in the game but open up as you progress through the story missions.

I can't remember the exact mission but it opens up when

> Master Smith is dying and you go to get a potion for him.

The weapon is also the King Skeletor.